# Executing Python scripts from windows path variable

Tags: python, path

I have Python 3.7 on my path (I can execute `.py` scripts when I am in that local directory in `cmd`)

I also have a folder of scripts on my path (I can open them from any local directory in `cmd` i.e. by typing "script.py")

However, I cannot execute these scripts from any local directory explicitly using `python`, i.e. "python script.py"

Any ideas why this is the case? Thanks

Edit:
The desired folder "scripts" is set in PYTHONPATH variable, and checking within python I see

> import sys
>
> sys.path
>
> ['', 'C:\Users\benma\Desktop\scripts',...

I can import a file from scripts into python already running, but not execute it directly

Comment: Seems you haven't add python path to environment variable? could you add your environment variable information?

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't search `PATH` to look for your scripts. You can run the script directly because the *shell* is searching `PATH` looking for something that matches.

[`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) won't help when executing from the shell. It is only used by Python when importing modules:

> Augment the default search path for module files.

I don't think you're going to get exactly what you're after. The closest is probably [executable modules](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ExecutableModules).